# Joining tables in SQL including count data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

A question I came across:

"Produce a list of department names and the number of people in each department?"

There are two tables, person and department. One of the fields in the person table is name. There aren't any department names given yet from the department table, same also for person, the name field is empty (no names under the name field).

Here is my code:

```
SELECT department.name from department
INNER JOIN COUNT(name) from person;
```

Comment: SELECT COUNT(person.name) ...BLAH JOIN...GROUP BY department.name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join both the tables considering that there exist a relationship between them. Assuming that person table has `department name` associated with it, you can use the below query which will get you the count of person per department

```
select department.name as DeptName,
count(p.name)
from department d
left join person p
on d.name = p.department_name
group by d.name
```